# move_uploaded_file failed to open stream and Permission denied error -wamp server with windows

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

i am running [wamp on windows 7](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

i am trying to upload some images via a form into my MVC applIcation. i am working from my laptop, so the Wamp is installed on my laptop

my problem is that i keep getting this message:

```
 Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:\Users\test\zend\\module\guest\src\guest/pics/holdover/pic.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
```

my problem is that i have not restricted any previged so i dont knwo why it would be restricted.

not-with-standing this, where do i go on my WAMP to enable access to the folder ?

thank you in advanced for your advise

**my Code:**

the aim of the file_upload is to transfer the file (currently held in a temp folder) to another folder. its also given a new name.

everything else work. the problem is with the permission of the receiving folder; permission is being denied

```
if ($form->isValid()) 
{       
    $size = new Size(array('min'=>2000)); //minimum bytes filesize

    $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
    $adapter->setValidators(array($size), $data['fileupload']['name']);
    if (!$adapter->isValid())
    {
        $dataError = $adapter->getMessages();
        $error = array();
        foreach($dataError as $key=>$row)
        {
            $error[] = $row;
        }
        $form->setMessages(array('fileupload'=>$error ));
    } 
    else
    {
        $fileName = $data['fileupload']['name']; 
        $fileTmpLoc = $data['fileupload']['tmp_name']; 
        $fileType = $data['fileupload']['type'];
        $fileSize = $data['fileupload']['size']; 
        $fileErrorMsg = $data['fileupload']['error'];
        $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName); 
        $this->fileExt = end($kaboom); 
        $this->fileName = "user_{$this->getAbbriviation($data)}{$this->getUserId()}.$this->fileExt";



        $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, dirname(__DIR__)."/pics/member/holdover/$this->fileName");

        if ($moveResult != true)
        {
            echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
            unlink($this->fileTmpLoc); 
            exit();
        }
        $this->processAndUploadPhotos($data);

        //  var_dump($moveResult); die();      
        $adapter->setDestination(dirname(__DIR__).'/testImage');
        if ($adapter->receive($data['fileupload']['name'])) {
            $profile->exchangeArray($form->getData());

            echo 'Profile Name '.$profile->profilename.' upload ';
        }
    }  
}
}
```

And the important bit

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Zend
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\zend\testingZend2\public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:\Users\zend\testingZend2\public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Show your PHP code that is doing the Upload. Edit your question to add the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the folder permissions using the chmod command try this command in you php script file.

```
 if( chmod($path, 0777) ) {

      move_uploaded_file($path)

 }
 else
    echo "Couldn't do it.";
```

Comment: WAMPServer runs on windows. You dont need to do this on windows.

Comment: hi Riggs. thank you for responce. but i am not clear of your anwer. where do i need to go so that i can change the permissions?

Comment: Can you please post the full code. so that we can suggest.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ya..that's true ..That's my mistake i didn't read the question properly

Comment: hi RiggsFolly. i added my code. but as, i said, the problem is in the receiving directory. This directory needs to be writable and have permsission to access

Comment: Make sure the user Apache runs as has full write access to the folder you're trying to move the files to (right click and click on sharing or permissions depending on the version of windows)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Virtual Host definition is giving access to `"C:\Users\zend\testingZend2\public"` but you are trying to store the images in a totally different folder `C:\Users\test\zend\\module\guest\src\guest/pics/holdover/pic.jpg`.

Not withstanding the double `\\` between zend and module, you will also have to give Apache access to this other folder structure.

So you need to add another `<Directory..` definition so Apache knows this site has access to the other folder structur as well as the folders it is running from.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Zend
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\zend\testingZend2\public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:\Users\zend\testingZend2\public">
       DirectoryIndex index.php
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "C:/Users/test/zend/module/guest/src/guest/pics/holdover">
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Its normal to do this with an alias like so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Zend
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\zend\testingZend2\public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:\Users\zend\testingZend2\public">
       DirectoryIndex index.php
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /pictures "C:/Users/test/zend/module/guest/src/guest/pics/holdover"
    <Directory "C:/Users/test/zend/module/guest/src/guest/pics/holdover">
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This allows you to use the alias i.e. pictures in your code rather than the full directory name.

Its also a good idea to stick to the Unix directory seperator in any files/directory information as PHP will do any necessary conversions to the DOS seperator automatically if it is running on DOS.

Comment: hi RiggsFolly; thanks for answer. i will try that now. i also tried to stick to UNix direcotory seperator but when i tired to seperate this the opposite way, the PHP could not interprete the last variable ; $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, dirname(__DIR__)."\pics\member\holdover\$this->fileName");

Comment: Thats because you have DOS seperators in a double quoted string. The backslash is the escape character when used in a double quoted string so to get a backslash into that you would have to do `move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, dirname(DIR)."\\pics\\member\\holdover\\$this->fileName");`. its easier to just do `move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, dirname(DIR)."/pics/member/holdover/$this->fileName");`

Comment: Hi RiggsFolloy; greatful for your help. i have tried your suggestions but i am still getting the same error message?is it possible that there is somthing else blocking the access. i mean, it worked 2 weeks ago when i first tried it. so, i dont know why its blocking now